# How to retain original Last Modified/Created date of the file on FTP when we try to download them using FTPClient Class and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ftp, automated-tests, ftp-client

Using this code, I was able to download the file, but the Last Modified date of the file is set as the value whenever I run the script.  How can I download the file without changing the Modification date, as it is needed for Validation.

```
package oops;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;


public class FTPDownloadFileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "test.rebex.net";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "demo";
        String pass = "password";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


            String remoteFile1 = "/readme.txt";
            File downloadFile1 = new File("C:\\project\\readme1.txt");
            OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
            boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
            outputStream1.close();

            if (success) {
                System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aliright, but can anyone help me out on how to use the suggested answer from the original question to use it in here (in my code)

Comment: I've posted there an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27013672/850848#49455929) that shows how (particularly the second part of my answer fits your code).

Comment: that helps! Cheers!